# Remote_Id_Length: Remote ID limit is 128 characters

Tags: authentication, open-id-connect

Does anyone know if there is a plan to increase the length of the identifier field to match the OpenId specs? Configuring an Auth. Provider using eIDAS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EIDAS) as the identity provider and I am facing a problem where the ThirdPartyAccountLink Id RemoteIdentifier field is only 128 chars length and the identifier returned by eIDAS can be more than 128 chars.
This is the error I am getting when trying to log in using eIDAS:

```
"We can’t log you in because of the following error. For more information, contact your Salesforce administrator.
Remote_Id_Length: Remote ID limit is 128 characters"
```

According to the OpenId specs, the maximum length should be 255 chars. Please see topic 2.2, the 'sub' description: https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html.

Is there a plan to increase the length of the identifier field to match the OpenId specs?

Thanks for your inputs (edited)

Comment: You're not in an OpenID Connect protocol sequence with your custom auth provider and `sub` is not a field in a data model, it's a claim in JWT produced by OIDC OP.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce to move up to 255 characters the maximum length. This is in the roadmap but there isn't any ETA at the moment